# Search inside multiple compressed files using 7zip and batch files and if result found, do soemthing

Tags: batch-file, command-line-interface, 7zip

I am trying to

- search inside multiple zip files for a specific filename
- if filename is NOT found, move said zip file to another folder
- Do the search without extracting the content
- Use batch and 7zip to achieve these results.

```
for %%f in (*.zip) do (
7z l "%%f" coolname.txt -r
if errorlevel 1 (echo archive %%f contains 1 coolname.txt) 
else (move "%%f" fixme)
)
```

I am trying to avoid, pushd, delayedexpansion, setlocal, usebackq, delims or tokens for simplicity sake, however if those are necessary, use them I shall

Comment: You've written some code, but you don't say what the problem you're encountering is. Just by glancing at it, I see that you need to put the `)` from the `if` statement on the same line as the `else`, but I don't know what other problems you're encountering.

Comment: The syntax usage for `IF ELSE` is clearly defined and shows an example of how to use it in the help file. Open up a cmd prompt and type `IF /?` to read the help.

Comment: I have tries a dozen versions of the else and if and none of them work. I have been working on this for like 4 hours.

Comment: There are only two syntax usage listed in the help file. I am not even sure how you could possibly think of writing it 10 other different ways.

Comment: `7z l` appears to return `errorlevel` as `0` regardless of whether the file was found or not.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with `7z`, but it sounds like you may have to pipe the output to `findstr` to detect whether it found the file or not.

Comment: Also, when you resolve the "does the .7z contain" problem, you should be aware that your code `move`s files that do not contain `coolwhatever` over `fixme`, so if you have 3 such .7z's , then the first one overwrites `fixme` **and deletes 1.7z**. The second one overwrites `fixme` **and deletes 2.7z**. The third one overwrites `fixme` **and deletes 3.7z**. So `fixme` will contain the original `3.7z` and `1.7z`, `2.7z` and `3.7z` will have been deleted.

Comment: the 10 different ways is multiple different `errorlevel` checks. Which like Magoo says, all show up as `0`... Annoying. I have also tried to use `findstr` but I was unable to make it work with if statements as it seems `findstr` is not a fan of the output of 7z. Hence me asking for help. I don't ask for help unless I am 100% stumped. But when I do, it seems all I get is help-shamed.

Also, yes, thank you for the note about `fixme`. However, I have a tested and working `robocopy` script instead of the move command. I just did not want to confuse people or take away from the question. /fail

Comment: I actually have a findstr test and it worked with extracting of the files.

  `"c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e "%%f" -o"tmp" cover.* -r | findstr "no files to process" > nul
  if not errorlevel 1 (robocopy "%cd%" "%cd%\fixme" "%%f" /mov > NUL | goto noresize)`

I just can not figure out how to make it work with the 7z 1 command which is search inside without extracting.

Comment: I actually do something very similar with Winzip in an automated process I have for a client.  My only thought is that 7zip is not writing to STDOUT and it writing directly to the console which FINDSTR wouldn't be able to parse.

Answer (score 1):

Change the value of `output_dir` to wherever you're actually putting the zip files that lack the file you're looking for, and change `prog_7z` to wherever you actually have 7-zip installed.

Either pass the folder that contains all of the subfolders as an argument to the script or simply drag that folder onto the script.

The main bit of the script is the last line, where you pass the output of `7z.exe l "filename"` to `findstr` and search for whatever you have stored in `%target_filename%`, then use `||` to say that if `errorlevel` isn't 0, then move that file to the other directory.

```
@echo off
set "output_dir=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\output_files"
set "prog_7z=E:\software\7-zip\7z.exe"
set "target_filename=coolname.txt"

if "%~1"=="" (
    echo USAGE: ZipSorter.bat ^<input_folder^>
    exit /b
) else (
    set "root_input_dir=%~1"
)

for /r "%root_input_dir%" %%A in (*.zip) do (
    %prog_7z% l "%%A" | findstr /C:"%target_filename%" || move "%%A" "%output_dir%"
)
```

Comment: I condensed it for testing and ran it, It moved everything lol. So I guess I will need to spend some more time testing `for /r "%cd%" %%A in (*.zip) do ("c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" l "%%A" | findstr /C:"cover.*" || move "%%A" "%cd%/tmp")`

Comment: Don't use wildcards in the `findstr` bit. I can only promise that the code I've posted works; I make no guarantees if you go and change things.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up taking SomethingDark's concept, butchering it and making it work. Thanks a ton fot the help man!

```
for /r "%cd%" %%a in (*.zip) do (
    "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" l "%%a" | findstr /i ".filename.jpg .filename.jpeg" 
    if errorlevel 1 robocopy "%cd%" "%cd%\notfound" "%%~nxa" /mov >nul & echo moved
)
```

note for the uninitiated. This is not searching for `.filename.jpeg.` It is searching for any file containing the words `filename` and `jpg` or `jpeg`. `findstr` uses `.` periods as wildcards lol. Quite the pain in the neck to make work. But close enough for now.

Also, I went with `robocopy` because it creates folders if they do not exist. Cleaner then `makedir` and `rd` to deal with folder creation.